# C# Generics: How to apply a generic type constraint AND inherit from basetype

Tags: c#, generics

This is what I am trying to do:

```
DataService<T> where T : SomeType : DataServiceBase
```

In other words, I want to introduce a T where it is a subclass of Sometype.  But I also need DataService to inherit from DataServiceBase.

It seems I can do one or the other, but not both because there are two colons used.  In other words, I can use the generic selector of " where : SomeType" or if I don't use that, I can inherit from DataServiceBase.  But if I do both, it generates a design time error.

Comment: But there isn't multiple inheritance in C#, wouldn't `DataService<T> where T : SomeType` imply `SomeType : DataServiceBase` somewhere along the chain also?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it to work like this:

```
DataService<T> : DataServiceBase where T : SomeType
```

Greg